# How can I silently install the Intel graphics driver (DCH)?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, batch, asus, portable-batch-system

I am trying to install the latest graphics drive package (DCH) silently. The suggested switches from the readme don't seem to do anything. Running `installer.exe -s` just produces the install windows (minimized) which is inaccessible.

The only recourse then is to kill the process or restart the PC. The readme lists all of the switches for `setup.exe`. There isn't one in the ZIP archive I have downloaded.

How can I install this driver silently?

How can I write a bat file myself for my computer's chipset?

Comment: To be able to tell you something intelligible more information is needed:  e.g. you need to tell what hardware this is for, what OS you're using, which driver you're attempting to install, what you have tried, where the readme is, what it contains.

Comment: I'm using windows 10 pro, I couldn't find chipset, how can I make a suitable bat file?

Comment: setupchipset.exe for chipset file

Comment: Please don't answer questions or add new info in comments. Rather [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1771996/edit) the question to keep it up-to-date and everything relevant readily available. Remember; we know only what you tell - I've got no clue what "setupchipset.exe for chipset file" means. Your question is marked for closure, so I'd suggest you update it as @Hannu requested. In the [Help](https://superuser.com/help) you'll find guidance for [how to ask a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask). Checking the Asking and Answering sections in Help is a good idea in general.

Answer (score 0):

This article may explain your problem:
[Intel DCH driver Silent Install Non-Interactive](https://community.intel.com/t5/Graphics/Intel-DCH-driver-Silent-Install-Non-Interactive/td-p/1437287/page/2).

An Intel moderator answered on January 2023 :

> I just confirmed, as you mentioned, that the solution or fix that will be supplied for this scenario, based on the article, will be provided for 10th-generation processors or higher, which will be available in future graphics driver releases.

If your processors or installation are older, or if the fix wasn't yet
made available by Intel, then the `-s` or `--silent` parameter won't be
available.

Comment: how do i know if intel chipset is old or new i want to do silent installation

Comment: this is mine https://www.intel.com.tr/content/www/tr/tr/products/sku/53445/intel-core-i52310-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-20-ghz/specifications.html

Comment: The [Intel Core i5-2310](https://www.techpowerup.com/cpu-specs/core-i5-2310.c732) is [Sandy Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandy_Bridge) technology which is second generation dating from May 2011, far from 10th-generation.